# Retrieving an image from parse.com in a List View using an Array Adapter

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter

I have data stored on parse.com.  I am trying to retrieve an image and a string and place it in a list view.  I have an adapter that I have been using to grab the text but unsure how to do with image.  There is one line in particular I need help with.

```
public class AppetizerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

protected Context mContext;
protected List mAppetizer;

public AppetizerAdapter(Context context, List appetizer) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_appetizers, appetizer);

    mContext = context;
    mAppetizer = appetizer;
}

// inflates each row of the app
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // initialize view holder
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) { // If no items in the view to be displayed
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.custom_appetizers, null);

        // initialize the views
        holder = new ViewHolder(); // creates a new view
        holder.aPPetizer = (TextView) convertView // calls the view
                .findViewById(R.id.appetizer);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.appetizerImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.appetizerImage);

        // call the view and setTag to the parameter (holder)
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else { // if view is previously displayed

        // initialize holder
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    // get the position of the row
    ParseObject appetizerObject = (ParseObject) mAppetizer.get(position);

    // title
    String appetizers = appetizerObject.getString("appetizers"); 
    holder.aPPetizer.setText(appetizers);

    // image
    ???
    holder.appetizerImage.setImageResource();

    return convertView; // return the view
}

public static class ViewHolder {

    // declaration of variables
    TextView aPPetizer;
    ImageView appetizerImage;

}
```

The part I am having a problem with is:

```
// title
String appetizers = appetizerObject.getString("appetizers");
```

This allows me to store the string in the column "appetizers" - which is a string, but for an image, I am not sure how to code this.

Comment: You can have it show the URL to the image

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: How are you adding items to your database?  Through your phone?  Or manually through the phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I have them in parse. Server is heroku

Comment: Yeah. I've no clue what that is. I will upvote your question and hope more people see it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can get your image's url from the `appetizerObject` reference, you will just need to download the bitmap from the network and set it as the ImageView's bitmap.

While there are many ways to implement it manually, i would recommend using a library to manage both the download and the caching process. From my experience, i have used the following libraries:

- Picasso: https://github.com/square/picasso
- Glide: https://github.com/Masterminds/glide

Both of them have a really simple (and similar) api.

Comment: I tried Picasso.  I added the dependency: compile ' com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' to the build.gradle.  I also added the .jar file but then i got an error that it was a duplicate and i remove it.  I don't know where to put MAVEN dependency?

Comment: For the image., i added another view (holder.appetizerImage) and this code below the code for the title: Picasso.with(getContext()).load(appObject.getParseFile("imageFiles").getUrl()).into(holder.appetizerImageView); -> gives me an error:  stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;at com.lizg.recipedirectory.AppetizerAdapter.getView(AppetizerAdapter.java:64) Line 64 is the code i wrote for the image starting with Picasso.with...

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? if so, you would only need to add `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` to your build.gradle (the one at app level). There's no need to add the .jar file if you are including it this way.

Comment: Yes, i am using Android Studio.  Ok good that is what i did but i am having a problem retrieving my image files from my backend server

Comment: I cleaned and rebuilt the project and it seems to work now :)